# HEROKU app not running with successful build error 503

Tags: node.js, heroku

Im very new at this. Im trying to run a node app on Heroku. it says the build was successful but it still wont run. ive tried multiple things maybe someone can point out to me why im getting an error. my github repository is https://github.com/kpacheco84/6-static_node_express.git any help is greatly appreciated [image]

```
HEROKU LOGS:
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version 12.x...
   Downloading and installing node 12.14.1...
   Using default npm version: 6.13.4
```

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules is checked into source control and cannot be cached

-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
      "TO LONG TO POST THIS PART JUST LISTING THE PACKAGES"-----> Build

```
-----> Caching build
   - node_modules

-----> Pruning devDependencies
   audited 258 packages in 1.155s
   found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
   Done: 26.5M
-----> Launching...
   Released v10
   https://katherinepacheco-portfolio.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: Heroku logs say anything?

Comment: i checked but nothing really :( just build succeeded

Comment: Looks like `Blocked a frame with origin`, do you have maybe an iframe accessing a different URL (than your app)? Thats no allowed due to same-origin policy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: :( not to sure what you mean by iframe?

Comment: have you tried "local" as in heroku local   cli command?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the hard coded port number in `app.js` `app.listen(5000, () => {....` with your `var port = ...` variable you've assigned earlier on in `app.js`.

Comment: just tried by updating that section with my port variable, still not working. I think im suppose to make the port something specific to HEROKU s server? but i dont see instructions to that affect

Comment: could not post the heroku logs as a comment so pasted it below my question....

Comment: @Beppe C by that iframe error, do you mean, i can not access another url from my app? for example, in my app i have links to GitHub Pages